# Получить ширину и высоту до загрузки файла

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли получить ширину и высоту изображения после того, как пользователь выбрал файл, но ещё его не загрузил на сервер?

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/data/settings/cover" class="d-none" id="cover__save">
<input type="file" name="img" id="cover__select" onchange="cover__account('save')">
</form>

<script>
function cover__account(act) {
   if (act == 'upload') {
     $('#cover__select').click();
   }

  if (act == 'save') {
    var height = 'ВЫСОТА ВЫБРАННОГО ФАЙЛА';
    var width = 'ШИРИНА ВЫБРАННОГО ФАЙЛА';

  if (height < 472) {
    alert('Высота не может быть менее 472px');
  }

  if (width < 1368) {
    alert('Ширина не может быть менее 1368px');
  }

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Делаете проверку на размер файла, после нажатия на кнопку проверяете совпадает ли она с Вашими требованиями, если нет, выкидываете оповещение.

Comment: посмотрите этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Comment: Вопрос в этом и заключается, как получить данные о выбранном файле?

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```